# how to open another view on same screen by clicking button in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to open a view on an another view by clicking button. I am attaching snap of it, for better understanding.

[This image is my desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFlmm.png)

[This image is my base view, which you can see in my desired one at the back side, with less opacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Hen.png)

**If anybody has idea, Please help me for this..**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library ([MZFormSheetPresentationController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetPresentationController)) to create the Alert like views with Images,Buttons and lots of functions. You can design viewController as you expected.

```
func formSheetControllerWithNavigationController() -> UINavigationController {
                return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "formSheetController") as! UINavigationController
}

func passDataToViewControllerAction() {

            let navigationController = self.formSheetControllerWithNavigationController()
            let formSheetController = MZFormSheetPresentationViewController(contentViewController: navigationController)
            formSheetController.presentationController?.isTransparentTouchEnabled = false
            formSheetController.presentationController?.shouldCenterVertically = true
            formSheetController.presentationController?.shouldCenterHorizontally = true
            formSheetController.presentationController?.shouldDismissOnBackgroundViewTap = true

            let yourViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as! EventDisplayViewController

            yourViewController.delegate = self



            self.present(formSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```